# Why cannot push 8-byte immediate value on stack in x86-64?

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64, instructions, instruction-set

I'm trying to understand x86-64 assembly and today I came across the following:

I can do something like this:

```
mov $0x74786574656d6f73, %rax #compiles to movabs
push %rax
```

While i can't do the following:

```
push $0x74786574656d6f73 #8-byte
```

I'm getting `Error: operand type mismatch for push`
I checked, and I can see, that there is no problem with doing:

```
push $0x74786574 #4-byte, compiles to pushq
```

Does it mean that I cannot push 8-byte immediate values on stack?

Comment: Default operand size in 64-bit mode is still 32-bit and 64-bit immediates are allowed only with `mov` instruction. See https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/a4/60/325383-sdm-vol-2abcd.pdf paragraph 2.2.1.5 Immediates

Comment: `movabs` is just AT&T syntax for a `mov` with a 64-bit immediate operand. It's not really different from `mov`, your disassembler just uses AT&T syntax, so it shows it with a different mnemonic. Speaking of which, assembly code doesn't "compile", it just assembles. And, in answer to your question, no, there is no instruction to push a QWORD (64-bit) immediate value onto the stack.

Comment: Thank you guys, that explains a lot.